# Prevent creation of empty log files if logger is disabled

Tags: python, logging

I am using logging module to write error and debug messages in seperate log files using the below code. But I want that the logging should happen only if a particular environment variable is set. In the below code, I had turned off the logging by setting `logger.disabled=True`. However, I am observing that when my application finishes execution, empty log files are present. I added a check to delete these files just after setting `logger.disabled=True` statement, but it says file doesn't exist. When are these files generated - at the end of execution of script even if logger is disabled, can the writing of empty files be prevented?

```
class LevelFilter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self, level):
        self.level = level
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.levelno == self.level

logger = logging.getLogger("exceptionsLogger")
debugLogFileHandler = logging.FileHandler("Debug.log", mode='w')
errorLogFileHandler = logging.FileHandler("Error.Log", mode='w')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
errorLogFileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
debugLogFileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(debugLogFileHandler)
logger.addHandler(errorLogFileHandler)
debugLogFileHandler.addFilter(LevelFilter(logging.DEBUG))
errorLogFileHandler.addFilter(LevelFilter(logging.ERROR))

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.disabled = True
```

Comment: My guess would be that this happens when the logger is used the first time. Maybe the `disabled` property is checked too late.

Comment: This is annoying unexpected behavior. A disabled logger definitely shouldn't create empty log files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See `logging/__init__.py` in the Python standard library. There is a class `FileHandler` which has a method `__init__()`.

`FileHandler.__init__` has an argument `delay` which makes the handler delay creation of the actual `StreamHandler` until first message emit. If you do not use this argument then `open()` is called with mode "w" at the moment you instantiate the `FileHandler` instance. You do it before you set `logger.disabled` to True.

So, even if you do not emit messages later you still already have an opened empty file.

To avoid this either create file handlers with argument `delay=True` or instantiate and assign handlers only when needed. `logger.disabled` won't help you avoid creation of files.